# UWP application can't read files after update

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have a Windows 10 application distributed on the Microsoft Store, after the latest update my application cannot open anymore files saved in the package LocalCache folder.
I think that could be something related to user permissions, because the application could still write files but couldn't read them, and deleting and reinstalling the application solves the issue.

Anyone have some idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

> UWP application can't read files after update

We can't reproduce this problem, derive from your description, it looks the folder permissions was destroyed after the OS update. When you reinstall the app, the folder permissions was rebuild. This is system level and more related with the OS update.

For your problem, reinstall the app is good practice currently, please feel free post this problem with windows feed back hub app.

Comment: You are welcome, if the answer is helpful please consider accept it thanks.